# The maximization of logdet

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

In wireless communication, the following is an important problem,

\begin{align}
\max_{X} \;\log\det&\big(I+X^HQX\big)\\
\text{s.t. tr}&\big(X^HX\big)\le 1,
\end{align}

where $X$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m>n$, and $Q$ is an $m\times m$ matrix with eigen-decomposition given by $Q=U\Sigma U^H$.

So, what's the solution of the proposed problem?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: $Q$ is presumably symmetric (or complex and Hermitian).  Is $Q$ positive semidefinite?

Comment: Are you interested only in closed form solutions, or would a reformulation as an SDP or other standard convex optimization problem be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, Q is positive semidefinte, and a closed-form solution is supposed